# Prove that the eigenvectors are independent.

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given two vectors $\boldsymbol\alpha=\left(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_N\right)^{T}$ and $\boldsymbol\beta=\left(\beta_1,...,\beta_N\right)^{T}$, let $M$ be the $N\times N$ matrix whose entries are expressed as

$$
M_{k,q}=\frac{\alpha_q}{\beta_k},\quad k=1,...,N,\quad q=1,...,N\quad ? 
$$

It's easy to see that $\boldsymbol\beta=\left(1/\beta_1,...,1/\beta_N\right)^{T}$ is eigenvector relative to the eigenvalue $\sum_{p=1}^{N}M_{p,p}$. Moreover it is easy to see that the $N$ vectors

$$
\mathbf{v}^{(p)} = \left(\begin{array}{c}
\frac{\alpha_p}{(N-1)\,\alpha_1}\\
\vdots\\
\frac{\alpha_p}{(N-1)\,\alpha_{p-1}}\\
-1\\
\frac{\alpha_p}{(N-1)\,\alpha_{p+1}}\\
\vdots\\
\frac{\alpha_p}{(N-1)\,\alpha_N}
\end{array}\right)\begin{array}{c}
\\
\\
\\
\leftarrow p\textrm{-th entry}\\
\\
\\
\\
\end{array},\quad p=1,...,N
$$
are all eigenvectors with eigenvalue zero. My guess is that only $N-1$ of them are independent, how can I prove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your $N\times N$ matrix is not entirely zero (which is the case here unless all $\alpha_i$ are zero) then it cannot have $N$ independent eigenvectors with eigenvalue$~0$. The kernel (eigenspace for $\lambda=0$) is of dimension at most $N-1$, and here in fact of dimension $N-1$ exactly (assuming $M\neq0$) since by the way it is constructed $M$ has rank$~1$. Note that this is even true if the trace of $M$ (the "other" eigenvalue $\sum_pM_{p,p}$) happens to be$~0$ too (if all its eigenvalues are zero then $M$ is nilpotent, but not necessarily zero).